# How to disable / enable checkbox base on select (option) value

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I was wondering how can i disable and enable a checkbox base on option value :
this is my code :

```
<select id="typeofworkday">
   <option value="lavorato" id="lavorato" name="lavorato"> lavorato </option>
   <option value="ferie" id="ferie" name="ferie"> ferie </option>
   <option value="malattia" id="malattia" name="malattia"> malattia </option>
```

```
<input type="checkbox" name="permesso" id="check1"  disabled="disabled" onclick="check();"> Permesso
```

if user select (lavorato) checkbox == enable else disable .

Comment: What part don't you know how to do? Where are you stuck? Show what you have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is listen to the select and react when it changes.

```
// Listen to the change of the <select> element
$("#typeofworkday").on("change", function() {
    // Check the option value for "ferie" and disable the checkbox
    if ($(this).val() === "ferie") {
        $("#check1").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    // For all other options, enable the checkbox
    } else {
        $("#check1").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

[Here's a JSFiddle of it working](http://jsfiddle.net/xf12zrs4/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('#typeofworkday').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() === 'lavorato') {
        $('#check1').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $('#check1').prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just a note... Your code would be cleaner if you just used the result of the equality comparison as the second argument to `.prop()`. *(Though it would need to be a "not equal" comparison.)* `$('#check1').prop("disabled", $(this).val() !== 'lavorato')`